Theta-characteristics on a genus 4 curve and $E_8$
In Symplectization, complexification and mathematical trinities Arnold writes: "I have heard from John McKay that the 27 straight lines on a cubical surface, the 28 tangents of a quartic plane curve and the 120 tritangent planes of a canonic sextic curve of genus 4 form a trinity parallel to  $E_6$, $E_7$ and $E_8$".
The first two "parallels" are well-known (they go back to E. Cartan). The tritangent planes to a canonical genus 4 curve are the odd theta-characteristics. Does anyone know a  relation of these with $E_8$? Unfortunately we can no longer ask McKay or Arnold….

Consider a quadric cone in $\mathbb P^3$ and its blowup, a Hirzebruch surface. Its intersection with a general cubic surface will be a genus 4 curve canonically embedded. The Hirzebruch surface admits a double cover branched at the union of the genus 4 curve and the exceptional divisor. This is a rational elliptic surface. The inverse image of the exceptional divisor is a zero section. With this zero section, the elliptic involution is the involution of the double cover — the elliptic curves are the inverse images of lines through the cone point. We can blow the zero section down to get a degree 1 Fano, which double covers the original cone. $-1$ curves on this Fano correspond to sections of the rational elliptic surface that don't intersect the zero section and to roots of $E_8$. There are 120 pairs of these exchanged by the involution. Each pair covers a single curve in the quadric cone. By some intersection theory one can check this must be the intersection of the cone with a plane, which splits into two $-1$ curves if and only if the plane is tritangent.

Great, thanks! Would you know a reference for this? It should be classical.

@abx: I do not.

"like through the cone point" = "lines through the cone vertex"?

I fixed the (what seemed to be) typo indicated by @მამუკაჯიბლაძე.

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე I didn't use the most precise language, but you understood my point.

Note also that the correspondence will not work for general curves of genus four. Let $U$ be the moduli of non-hyperelliptic genus four curves and let $D \subset U$ be the divisor parametrizing curves with a vanishing thetanull. Let $V \to U$ be the cover parametrizing odd theta characteristics, and let $E = V\times_{U} D$.  Then Will Sawin's argument above (or the classical description of degree one del Pezzos) show that the monodromy of $E \to D$ is $W(E_{8})/(\pm 1)$. In contrast the monodromy of $V \to U$ is the subgroup $O^{+}_{8}(2)$ by Mumfrord's analysis of theta characteristics.

Adding to @TonyPantev comment: The correspondence outlined in the answer is the one between degree 1 Del-Pezzo surfaces and genus 4 curves admitting a theta null (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605592 for the strongest version of this claim). Indeed the subgroup of $O_8^+(2)$ fixing an even point is $W(E_8)/\pm1$

Quoting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_Pezzo_surface :

Degree 1: they have 240 (−1)-curves corresponding to the roots of an
E8 root system. They form an 8-dimensional family. The anticanonical
divisor is not very ample. The linear system |−2K| defines a degree 2
map from the del Pezzo surface to a quadratic cone in P3, branched
over a nonsingular genus 4 curve cut out by a cubic surface.
Degree 2: they have 56 (−1)-curves corresponding to the minuscule
vectors of the dual of the E7 lattice. They form a 6-dimensional
family. The anticanonical divisor is not very ample, and its linear
system defines a map from the del Pezzo surface to the projective
plane, branched over a quartic plane curve. This map is generically 2
to 1, so this surface is sometimes called a del Pezzo double plane.
The 56 lines of the del Pezzo surface map in pairs to the 28
bitangents of a quartic.
Degree 3: these are essentially cubic surfaces in P3; the cubic
surface is the image of the anticanonical embedding. They have 27
(−1)-curves corresponding to the minuscule vectors of one coset in the
dual of the E6 lattice, which map to the 27 lines of the cubic
surface. They form a 4-dimensional family.

As usual in classical algebraic geometry, it's helpful to consult "Classical Algebraic Geometry" by Dolgachev (which is also available online, now in a new shiny edition: https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/lecturenotes.html ).
The relevant parts are the sections about degrees 1,2 in the Del-Pezzo surfaces chapter, and the chapter about cubic surfaces (which are degree 3 Del-Pezzo surfaces)
